# Cross-platform image file size, the same?

Tags: graphics, luatex, cross-platform

My application needs to know the exact file size (bytes) of *.png image files. This works exactly as expected on Linux:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphics}
\gdef\getfilesize#1{%
  \directlua{
    local filename = ("\luaescapestring{#1}")
    local foundfile = kpse.find_file(filename, "tex", true)
    if foundfile then
      local size = lfs.attributes(foundfile, "size")
      if size then
        tex.write(size)
      end
    end
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image-4x3.png}\par
Above file size: \getfilesize{example-image-4x3.png}\par
\end{document}
```

It reports file size 1247, which is correct. Alas, I have no access to other operating systems (Windows, Mac). Would this also work there? Would the reported value be the same, on different systems?

EDIT: What I mean is: Among those who see this question, and use Windows (MiKtex), does the above code report the same number that I get on Linux? It is printed in the PDF. Should be the same, but I want to be sure.

Why I do this: Use of images is limited. To ensure that an image is "the same as previously approved" rather than "edited by someone along the way" there are several checks, such as file size.

Comment: should be the same but why use size rather than the md5 hash which all tex engines can generate these days

Comment: but anyway png files are platform independent so they should be bitwise identical if moved from one platform to another

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The MWE is part of a larger body of code, with other things happening. An md5 would not suffice, since TeX does not know the md5 in advance. But allowed images will have filesize in a very limited byte range. Edited images (without expertise) would have byte size outside the range. As you noted, png byte size should be the same. But operating systems sometimes do unexpected things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lfs.attributes()` uses `stat()` system call according to [its document](https://lunarmodules.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html#reference) which should produce identical result for files on Linux, macOS, Windows, and [by POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) the size is the actual size of the file (after symbolic link is resolved). So it is safe to use that method to get file size. If you don't feel that is safe enough a common practice used in lua to get file size using seek can be used, see the other answer I posted.

Answer (score 2):

In general situations `lfs.attributes()` can be trusted to work cross platform.
A slower but guaranteed to work alternative:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
%\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphics}
\gdef\getfilesize#1{%
  \directlua{
    function fsize (file)
      local h = io.open(file)
      local size = h:seek("end")
      assert(h:close())
      return size
    end
    local filename = ("\luaescapestring{#1}")
    local foundfile = kpse.find_file(filename, "tex", true)
    if foundfile then
      local size = fsize(foundfile)
      if size then
        tex.write(size)
      end
    end
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image-4x3.png}\par
Above file size: \getfilesize{example-image-4x3.png}\par
\end{document}
```

Modified from:
https://www.lua.org/pil/21.3.html

Comment: I believe the methods are slightly different: My method works quickly (on my system), possibly because it merely gets the system's own data, without actually opening the file. But methods that involve opening the file take more time. May be system-dependent.

Comment: @rallg I tired to investigate how reliable the `stat()` sys call used by `lfs.attributes` is and it is by POSIX standard return the actual size of file. Testing your code on Linux/macOS/Windows with an image I created does produce identical file size. So I can conclude the method you use are at least safe for these platforms.

Comment: LdBeth - If you post that as an answer, I will accept it. Just what I needed to know! For some reason the `@` reply method is not working here.